# I'm using XQUERY, I have 500 records saved in Database, I want to extract only n number of records from it, according to my need

Tags: xquery

Suppose I want to extract only 5 records from database, then what to do ?
 How to write query for it?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the database? In case you actually mean SQL query, read : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: You have to be **much** more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information about your case, I would recommend the `subsequence` function: `subsequence($records, 1, 5)`

Comment: Sure, glad to hear it helped. If it answered your question, please mark it as the answer. (So a green check mark appears next to the answer.)